# How to get retwets and favorites of of the tweets queried in Twitter4J?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm using the following code to get the twitter results using twitter4j api of a particular hashtag, say for example #Something. I can obtain 100 tweets but how do I get the amount of retweets and favorites of each tweet obtained?

```
        Query query = new Query("#SOMETHING");
        query.setCount(100);
        QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
        for (Status status : result.getTweets()) 
        {
            sb.append(status.getText()+"\n");
        }
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("OutputFile.txt");
        out.print(sb);
        out.close();
```

How can I get the retweets and favorites of all the tweets obtained above? Say for example into two separate arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Need to use `getRetweetCount()` and `getFavoriteCount()` in the for loop for each tweet.

```
        for (Status status : result.getTweets()) 
        {
            System.out.println("RT "+status.getRetweetCount());
            System.out.println("FAV "+status.getFavoriteCount());
            sb.append(status.getText()+"\n");
        }
```